# MIT License - Dual Authors

Tags: licensing

For an open source project created by 2 authors, is it proper for an MIT License to have two authors?

```
The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2016 FIRST NAME and SECOND NAME
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be okay?  Copyright can be owned by multiple authors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​